# How to call a JavaScript function from "ColdFusion button"

Tags: ajax, function, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have a prototype function. I would like to wrap it around function tag and then call it from a button in a cfform. Is it possible to do it? and how would I do it?

I tried this, but I got an error said the array is not defined. All Helps are appreciated.

```
<cfscript >
    function calculateTotal(){
        var Price = Array();
        var Quantity = Array();
            $$('.x-grid3-col-PRICE').each(function(el){Price[Price.length] = el.innerHTML; });
            $$('.x-grid3-col-QUANTITY').each(function(el){Quantity[Quantity.length] = parseInt(el.innerHTML); });

        var Totals = 0;
        for (var index = 0; index < Price.length; ++index) {
            if (!isNaN(Price[index]) && !isNaN(Quantity[index]))
             {
             Totals =  Totals + (Price[index] * Quantity[index]);
                    }

                }
        $('total').value = Totals;
       return true;
    }
    </cfscript>

<cfform>
     <cfinput type="Button" name="submit" value="Calculate Order" onclick="#calculateTotal()#">
    <cfinput type="Text" name="total" disabled="true" label="Total $" size="5">
</cfform
```

Comment: Reading this - http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2012/10/the-coldfusion-requestresponse-process.html - might help you revise your expectations as to how things come together when a browser makes a request etc.

Comment: Thanks Adam, That is really helpful. Great Articles too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So After reading the article of Adam Cameron, I found a way to work the problem. Instead of wrapping the function in a `<cfscript>` tag, I wrapped it with `<cfsavecontent>`. Just in case someone out there looking for same question, here is how I did it.

Basically, I put the javascript function code in the `cfsavecontent` tag with a variable, so when the server talk to CMFL, it only passes on the variable "calculatetotal" in the compilation.

```
<cfsavecontent variable="calculateTotal">
        var Price  = Array();
        var Quantity = Array();
            $$('.x-grid3-col-PRICE').each(function(el){Price[Price.length] = el.innerHTML; });
            $$('.x-grid3-col-QUANTITY').each(function(el){Quantity[Quantity.length] = parseInt(el.innerHTML); });

        var Totals = 0;
        for (var index = 0; index < Price.length; ++index) {
            if (!isNaN(Price[index]) && !isNaN(Quantity[index]))
             {
             Totals =  Totals + (Price[index] * Quantity[index]);
                    }

                }
        $('total').value = Totals;
       return true;
</cfsavecontent>


<cfform name="display" format="html">
         <cfgrid name= "cart" query="getdtls" selectmode="edit"  width="580" format="html">
            <cfgridcolumn name="chargename" header="Charge Type" dataalign="right" select="No" >
            <cfgridcolumn name="price" header="price"type="numeric"  dataalign="right" select="No" >
            <cfgridcolumn name="quantity" header="Quantity" type="numeric"  dataalign="right"  >               
        </cfgrid>
       <cfinput type="Button" name="calculateBtn" value="Calculate Order" onclick="#calculateTotal#">
       <cfinput type="Text" name="total" disabled="true" label="Total $" size="5">

    </cfform>
```

Comment: Many thanks mate. I am new to ColdFusion. This action makes feel like asp.net where you HAVE by default an ability to run any user-mode code on a server (runat="server" attribute) thru callbacks aka events.

Answer (score 5):

The way you are trying to do this is not possible.

You cannot call a ColdFusion function by clicking a button without using some kind of http request, such as via AJAX. ColdFusion is server side code, the `onclick` is client side, without making some kind of request to the server, these two cannot interact with each other.

You would need to either, rewrite the function in JavaScript or rewrite the code to make an AJAX request to run the ColdFusion function.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to call a coldfusion function on click of HTML element. It is like using coldfusion(sever side language) as client side language. The method you are trying to do will print the value of function inside the html element like this

```
      <cfform>
       <cfinput type="Button" name="submit" value="Calculate Order" onclick="**true**">
       <cfinput type="Text" name="total" disabled="true" label="Total $" size="5">
      </cfform>
```

Using #calculateTotal()# inside onclick : Function will be called when the page is loaded, not on click.

If you want to use onclick function using coldfusion instead of javascript/jquery, you could use  tag like this-

```
    <cfsavecontent variable="calculateTotal">
            //your code you want to execute
    </cfsavecontent>

    <cfform>
       <cfinput type="Button" name="submit" value="Calculate Order" onclick="#calculateTotal#">
       <cfinput type="Text" name="total" disabled="true" label="Total $" size="5">
    </cfform>
```